# Disable Tomcat/Jetty ETag or cache in development, not working on IOS

Tags: ios, tomcat, jakarta-ee, safari, jetty

Anyone knows if there is a way to disable tomcat etag caching ( in development ) or whatever mechanisms it is using ?

**Its not really working well in ios browser.**

When I **change a file**, I refresh the iPhone safari browser, but nothing gets updated. I can do this twenty times and still same results.

However, when I then **refresh my chrome** browser on my desktop computer, it gets refreshed as usual. I can **then go the safari** browser and refresh and voila, it refreshes.

It makes me believe that it is communicating with the server each time, ( i can see on the logs as well ) but tomcat and jetty might be **responding to use** local cache, since **it deems nothing** has changed.

Which is not really true. I am not sure why tomcat threats Chrome and IOS differently, but it seems to be doing that. Or that IOS is not respecting my cache invalidation on the **headers**:

```
response.setDateHeader( "Expires"      , 0                                                                           );
response.setDateHeader( "Last-Modified", new Date().getTime()                                                        );
response.setHeader    ( "Pragma"       , "no-cache"                                                                  );
response.setHeader    ( "Cache-Control", "max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate" );
```

But this is not working for either Tomcat or Jetty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appearantely, Java is to blame once again.

I am serving my contents from a URL and I just discovered that it caches them by default.

To prevent it from caching you need to KNOW to set

```
   url.openConnection().setUseCaches(false);
```

Which makes we wonder, what other classes this might be repeating itself.

Really clever Java, do the caching for me. Like I can't deal with that myself if I need to.